# Failed to launch Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Last week after I update the Jupyter notebook, its launching started to fail. I tried to update anaconda, anaconda-navigator and updater. These all did not work.

The errors are as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/charcoalp/anaconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/charcoalp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 46, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/home/charcoalp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/home/charcoalp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/charcoalp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/home/charcoalp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/home/charcoalp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: libsodium.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have used this to do python's work for a year, appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try solving it by installing the missing lib in conda. Type in a terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge libsodium
```